# addresses of labels in assembly 80x86

Tags: assembly

I have a general question on labels in assembly.

If I have this code:

> func_start:
>
> ; Some code here
>
> func_end:

Which label has higher address?

Answer (score 2):

If it's written like that, in traditional assembly code, func_end will have the higher address.  As a rule, program flows from lower-to-higher address.  As the program counter increases with every instruction executed, moving forward through the program memory.